# Vagrant Up not working

Tags: vagrant, provider

I have issues running vagrant up command on windows 7,I have followed all the  steps mentioned in this [**link**](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/index.html)

When I run the command `vagrant up --provider=hashicorp/precise32`, in command prompt,I get the following error.

> The provider 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found, but was
>   requested to back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that
>   exists.

I have also disabled the Antivirus before installation, but that did not help.

Comment: Hi! hashicorp/precise32 is not a provider but it' a box.. Have you init your configuration (this metod vagrant init hashicorp/precise32 ) ?? After this comand you can try to run vagrnat up" without other options

Comment: Make sure you cd into the right directory. A simple vagrant up command without flags should work if you're in the directory with the Vagrantfile and box file.

Answer (score 14):

Vagrant works with some [Providers](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/providers/), as VirtualBox, Xen, VMWare, AWS, Digital Ocean and Docker.

The [hashicorp/precise32](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise32) is a [box](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes.html). After Vagrant 1.5 the [Vagrant Cloud](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search) is available.

For use Vagrant, following the steps:

- Install [Vagrant](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/installation/index.html)
- Install a provider, as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
- Create a new folder, as `project`
- Open folder `project`
- [Execute](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/init.html) `vagrant init hashicorp/precise32`
- [Execute](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/up.html) `vagrant up --provider=virtualbox` or just `vagrant up`